# My USB drive is corrupted and read only

Tags: usb, mount, data-corruption

I have a problem:
My USB drive (SanDisk) is corrupted and marked as read only.

When trying to mount it in the terminal it throws the following error:

```
Error opening '/dev/sdd1' read-write
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdd1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Running `chkdsk E: /f` on Windows results in the following:

```
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Windows cannot run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected.
```

Running `chkdsk E:` on Windows returns the following:
https://pastebin.com/BaFsZTz8

I also can't format or delete partitions on Windows and Ubuntu.

Any advice?

Comment: This may help https://www.lifewire.com/fix-usb-drive-with-ubuntu-4050141

Comment: @David I can't create a new file system, getting the following error: "Can't write to /dev/sdd, because it is opened read-only."

Comment: Is there a switch on the drive. The instructions there should wipe the partition table and make a new one.

Comment: @David No, it does not have any switch to turn on write protection. Following the instructions didn't help me either, doing anything returns either "Read-only file system" or "Can't write to /dev/sdd, because it is opened read-only.".

Comment: USB flash media is cheap storage that isn't designed for heavy or long-term use in my opinion. Each write of data risks damage to the media that corrupts part of the drive, and once one part is corrupted permanently the device isn't worth the effort trying to fix (unlike hard drive or ssd drives which have diagnostics & fix procedures)... it's generally cheaper to through the device away & replace.... it's a consumable medium...